# Functional equation substitution

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

For functional equations like $f(f(n)) + f^2(n) = n^2 + 3n + 3 $, can you make substitutions like $f(n) = g(n) + kn + c$, where $g(n)$ has no constant terms or any terms of $n$ ( if $g(n)$ itself does not contain any constant terms or terms of $n$, we can set $k = 0$ and $c = 0$)

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you mean.
Suppose
$$
f(f(n)) + f(n)^2 = n^2 + 3n + 3
$$
for all $n$.  Substutute
$$
f(n) = g(n) + kn + c
\tag{1}$$
 to get
$$
g \left( g \left( n \right) +kn+c \right) +kg \left( n \right) +{k}^{2
}n+kc+c+ \left( g \left( n \right)  \right) ^{2}+2\,g \left( n
 \right) kn+2\,g \left( n \right) c+{k}^{2}{n}^{2}+2\,knc+{c}^{2}={n}^
{2}+3\,n+3
$$
We can do this if we know the functions $f$ and $g$ are related by $(1)$.  Or, if we do not already have a $g$ to use, we can rearrange $(1)$ as
$$
g(n) = f(n) - kn - c
\tag{2}$$
and take that as the definition of the function $g$.